# has_many :through, nested polymorphic relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

Is there a way to directly reference (using rails directly, without resorting to a lot of custom SQL) a relation that is nested behind a polymorphic relation?  In the below example, is there a way to define a has_many relation in User that references LayerTwo?

I'd like to do (in User)

```
has_many :layer_twos, :through => layer_ones
```

but this approach doesn't take into the account of the previously specified has_many relations through the polymorphic relation.  Any suggestions?   It may not be possibly through the existing rails conventions, but figured I'd defer the question to people smarter then myself.

```
class CreateOwners < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :owners do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.references :owned, :polymorphic => :true
      t.references :user
    end     
    create_table :layer_ones do |t|
    end
    create_table :layer_twos do |t|
      t.references :layer_one
    end
  end
end


class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :owned, :polymorphic => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owners
  has_many :layer_ones, :through => :owners, :source => :owned, :source_type => 'LayerOne'
end

class LayerOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owners, :as => :owned
  has_many :layer_twos
end

class LayerTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :LayerOne
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted now that Rails 3.1 has nested has_many :through associations built in. [an ASCIIcast on this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, ActiveRecord does not support :through a :through relationship. You can work around this using some tricks and hacks, such as creating a VIEW which remaps the relationship into a more direct one, which can simplify your ActiveRecord model at the expense of database complexity.

Polymorphic associations are particularly ornery.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to be verify that with someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of its support for nesting through polymorphic asociations but it might be worth checking out the [`nested_has_many_through`](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through) plugin, which from the README:

> …makes it possible to define
>   has_many `:through` relationships that
>   go through other `has_many` `:through`
>   relationships, possibly through an
>   arbitrarily deep hierarchy. This
>   allows associations across any number
>   of tables to be constructed, without
>   having to resort to `find_by_sql` (which
>   isn't a suitable solution if you need
>   to do eager loading through `:include`
>   as well).

Comment: Yes, this will work.  You just have to be careful not to nest too deeply and bog down your app.  I wrote a blog post showing the step-by-step: http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Rails 3):

```
class LayerOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def layer_twos
      LayerTwo.where(:layer_one_id => all.map(&:id))
    end
  end
end
```